# having trouble with using 'for' loop in a scenario

Tags: python

I have a scenario in which some vehicles are forced to slow down now and then. So, I used the "loop for" of python and "traci.vehicle.slowDown()" method of my simulator for generating the conditions. But, as soon as the first added vehicle leaves the network, the simulation is terminated by the error saying " vehicle 'myvehicle' is not known". I know this is due to the "loop for" but, what is the solution to make the vehicles slow down repeatedly?
Here is what I am using:

```
def slowdown():
    traci.start(sumoCmd)
    traci.vehicle.add(vehID = "c1", typeID = "car1", routeID = "route_1", departLane='0', depart = "30")
    
    N = 1000
    step = 0
    for step in range(N):
        if step % 10 == 5:
            traci.vehicle.slowDown("c1", 0, 5)
        traci.simulationStep()    
    traci.close()
    sys.stdout.flush()
slowdown()
```

Comment: maybe explain the code a bit.
As the code stands, this is what I've understood
you only add 1 car 'c1' in the variable
then you use a loop which is again calling the same function (recursive call) so it should keep running infinitely ideally.
But your error is myvehicle is not even defined in the piece of code you've shared so maybe some insights on that ?

Comment: @ Muhammad Ahmed, as I mentioned, a vehicle 'c1' is added at step '30' of simulation. I want to make it slow down at the time step defined by 'step % 10 == 5'. I added more vehicles previously but nothing changed. 'myvehicle' stands for each vehicle insert the simulation with these definitions like 'c1' and so on.

Comment: Nothing seems wrong with your loop from a python programming perspective. I do not know `traci`, but I guess there is a method or property in `traci.vehicle` to check which ids are known. If yes, you could avoid the error by just slowing down known ids.

Comment: @Carlos Horn, the vehicle 'c1' leaves the network before ending the N and no longer exists while by using the 'for' loop, we issue a command to recall the 'c1' vehicle again.